# MySQL ERROR 1064 (42000) when creating a table

Tags: mysql

I've looked at previous posts but I am struggling to figure out where i am going wrong.
I am trying to create a table using this code:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Engine
-> (
-> ID VARCHAR(255) UNASSSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
-> Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
-> Displacement VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
-> Code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
-> PowerOutput VARCHAR(10),
-> MadeAt VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY (ID),
-> FOREIGN KEY (MadeAt)
-> );
```

However I am repeatedly getting this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNASSSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
```

Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Displace' at line 3

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
ID VARCHAR(255) UNASSSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
```

into:

```
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

`UNASSIGNED` should be `UNSIGNED`, but it is not necessary to define this, because `AUTO_INCREMENT` will start at `1` by default when not defined otherwise. `UNIQUE` is redundant as well, because the ID will increment and the numbers will be unique anyway.

In most cases `VARCHAR` is not recommended to use as `PRIMARY KEY`.